# Calling a mailer from a different mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I want a mailer class (let's say `UserMailer`) to call a method on another mailer class (let's say `LoggerMailer`) when `UserMailer`'s method is called. My code is like this:

#### app/mailers/logger_mailer.rb

```
class LoggerMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def log_mail(...)
    ...
    mail(layout: ..., template: ..., to: ..., from: ..., subject: ..., ...)
  end
end
```

#### app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def some_mail_method(...)
    ...
    LoggerMailer.log_mail(...)
    mail(layout: ..., to: ..., from: ..., subject: ..., ...)
  end
end
```

`UserMailer#some_mail_method` is the main mail method, and when this is called, I want it to call `LoggerMailer#log_mail` in addition to its own `mail` method call.

However, when I call `UserMailer#some_mail_method`, it does not seem to call `LoggerMailer#log_mail`. I feel so because when I put a line `binding.pry`  within the method body of `LoggerMailer#log_mail`, it does not seem to stop at that point.

1. Is `LoggerMailer.log_mail` actually called?
2. In general, is it possible or not to call a mailer method from the method body of another mailer method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that mailer methods don't send anything on their own, they (by calling `mail`) just return `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` instances and then someone calls `deliver_now` or `deliver_later` on that `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` to actually arrange delivery.

When you do this:

```
LoggerMailer.log_mail(...)
```

you're calling the mailer but throwing away the `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` that it returns so nothing useful happens.

You need to deliver the log mail:

```
LoggerMailer.log_mail(...).deliver_now
```

You could also put the `LoggerMailer.log_mail` and `UserMailer. some_mail_method` messages in a wrapper that would forward the `deliver_now` or `deliver_later` methods when the caller gets around to trying to deliver the `some_mail_method`.